# Android - Play sound from microphone with different frequency

Tags: android, audio

I want to make an Android app that listens to the microphone, and plays the exact same sound to the speaker, but with only the frequency changed.
Say I want to play always double the frequency compared to the input.
I tried to use a tuner, and use that frequency to play a new note using the AudioTrack class, but it sounds nothing like the input. (I guess because the overtones are gone.)

So I do already know the frequency of the input, but I want to change the frequency and not just play a new note, because it will sound very different.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance,
Jeroen D.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a signal processing issue, rather than the programming issue.

You are right, all natural sounds like human voice have a wide range of frequencies. So you cannot approximate the mic input by a single frequency and simply change that frequency. Instead, you need a sort of "modulation" technique: filters the input with a low-pass filter, multiplies it by another sine wave, removes the image, and feeds the final results to AudioTrack. Please refers to the textbook "signals and systems" for fundamentals.

Comment: Thanks, I came up with an idea: if I know the amplitude at a specific time, i can use sine regression to get the sine equation,and thus the frequency. But would this also solve the overtone problem? I assume the microphone does record all overtones, so just calculating all sine functions for each amplitude at one point should give the solution right?

Comment: You're partially right. Any tone can be represented by the combination of multiple sine/cosine waves. The most efficient way to get coefficients of sine/cosine waves is fft. You need to group the audio data samples to do fft, rather than do it sample by sample. A single data point does not contain any mean of frequency, while only a piece of data does.